# chrome has cached html file that no longer exists on server

Tags: html, .htaccess, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

There was a static site with no cache control: site.com/index.html

now there is: site.com/index.php
(index.html is deleted)

On chrome (where the old website has been opened before)
chrome shows cached version index.html

Seems chrome loads the site without contacting the server

.htaccess

```
   <FilesMatch ".(css|html|swf)$">
       Header unset Cache-Control
   </FilesMatch>
```

any other .htaccess variations on cache busting do not work because chrome doesn`t seem to contact the server

Comment: After much reading it seems chrome caching simply works this way and sadly there is no way around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal behavior because you told Chrome before that it can cache your file. So it has no reason to ask the server because it already knows your file was not updated (which you know is wrong but you can't tell the browser).

You have to delete the cache in your browser.
The same effect will happen with all current browsers.

If the old and new index page both include a JavaScript which is not cached you could use the script to trigger a redirect to index.PHP or a subpath

To find out when the cached files will expire you might want to try [ChromeCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) and its teammates for [Internet Explorer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ie_cache_viewer.html) and [Firefox](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html), this will give you an impression when the cached files expire on your machine. After that you will know how long it is probably going to take until all your customers get the new version without purging their caches.

[image: Chrome Cache View showing expiration time]

Comment: You should tell us more about the structure of your site. You have a Problem because it is the default page thats cached, otherwise you could use URL fingerprinting or a New Name for the updated resource

Comment: Old site was made in Adobe Muse - several html files and images folder. The new site (Joomla) sets cache headers properly. But chrome still see old site. Since asking the question I have read a lot on this problem and it seems there is no solution. I'm working on reaching visitors through other channels (twitter,fb)

Comment: @ArmandP no JavaScript or image that is not cached ? You could use them to redirect or show an image which tells your user to clear the cache. Otherwise you need to wait for the cache to expire

Comment: No - everything seems to be cached.

It would be interesting to know when Chrome clears cache automatically for page with no expire information set.

Comment: @ArmandP Please have a look at my edit, this might help finding out when the caches expire on their own

Answer (score 1):

Normally browser caches js, css and image files.To load these updated files,
there are too may solutions.

- Press Ctrl+f5.
- Use incognito window.
- Clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete cache controle in .htaccess and redirect users from url to another and  then wait for some time and check your website again.